# Swagger/OpenAPI: is it fine send a content application/json although we don't expect any response body?

Tags: rest, swagger, openapi

While integrating an external RESTful service I experience the problem that my generated Java code sends and empty `Accept` header. The external service seems to only accept a request without an Accept header or `Accept: application/json`.

I was able to resolve the problem by defining the `content` in the success response. However I am not sure if this is best practice to resolve this problem as we don't expect any response:

```
    "responses": {
      "204": {
        "description": "No Content",
        "content": {                     <- these lines
          "application/json": {          <- these lines
          }
        }
      },
      "400": {
        "description": "Bad Request"
      },
      "401": {
        "description": "Unauthorized"
      },
      "500": {
        "description": "Internal server error"
      }
    },
```

Comment: Is your API definition `swagger: '2.0'` or `openapi: 3.0.x`?

Comment: `openapi: 3.0.0`